# Install Thelia 2 on Mac with Php intl issue

Tags: php, macos, symfony, intl

I am trying to install [Thelia 2](http://thelia.net/) on XAMPP on Mac. However, I get stuck with the error message on step 2:

[image]

I tried a lot of things and am pretty sure intl is enabled:

```
$ php -m | grep intl

intl
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must check if intl is installed using phpinfo() function via apache (or nginx). Using php cli only show you the conf for this sapi. Your php configuration can be different between cli and apache (or nginx, cgi, etc).

So put a file info.php for example and call phpinfo() function in it. Then display this page throw you web browser.

Comment: You're right, I alternatively installed MAMP and fixed the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

intl is a little tricky on windows and mac with some preconfigured env. There is a little trick to activate this extension.

you have to copy all files named icu***.dll or icu***.so from your php directory to the apache directory.

on Windows with Wamp the directories are "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.xx" "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.xx\bin".

Comment: Great idea. If someone wants to use the built-in Apache on Mac, this is definitely the solution. Thanks!